# In MySQL what does the regex statement '\w' do or return?

Tags: mysql, regex

In MySQL what does the regex statement `... REGEXP '\w'` do/return?
Is it at all like the Perl `\w`?

Comment: I'm not sure if the regex `\w` will do anything in MySQL as it's run on the POSIX ERE engine.  You might want to try `[:word:]`.  But basically, it's the same as `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Comment: @Benjam is correct. In my test, `REGEXP '\w'` just returns values containing the letter `w`

Answer (score 4):

It selects values containing 'w'.
Check: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html